# How to extract multiple strings from a line using SED regex in Linux and write them to a file?

Tags: linux, sed

I have an XML file with multiple lines like below ( I only care about the lines that start with SOURCE)

```
SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Oracle" DBDNAME ="OrclExp11g" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="EMPLOYEES" OBJECTVERSION ="1" 

SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" DATABASETYPE ="Oracle" DBDNAME ="OrclExp11g" DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="HR" OBJECTVERSION ="1"
```

In every line that starts with SOURCE I need to get 3 strings and write them to another file like below.

Oracle,OrclExp11g,EMPLOYEES

Oracle,OrclExp11g,HR

```
sed -n -e '/SOURCE /p' InputFile.XML | sed -r 's/.* NAME \=\"(.+)\" OBJECTVERSION \=\".*/\1/'  > $Source_List.Out
```

I am new to using SED but so far I was able to get out only one string out using SED. I really appreciate if anyone can help me how to get 3 strings out. 
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guessed `sed` is your friend, you could replace matched regex using `\1`,`\2` and so on.

```
$ sed -nE '/SOURCE/{s/^.*DATABASETYPE ="([^"]*)".*DBDNAME ="([^"]*)".*NAME ="([^"]*)".*$/\1,\2,\3/;p}' file >outputfile
```

**Output**

```
$ cat outputfile
Oracle,OrclExp11g,EMPLOYEES
Oracle,OrclExp11g,HR
```

---

**Notes**

- `-E` enable extended regex.
- `-n` with sed suppresses the normal output. Only the lines that you would print with `p` will be printed.

Comment: Thank you so much sjsam for your solution. This worked like a charm. (I just had to add a space in front of NAME just to avoid greedy search)

Comment: @Kris : Thanks for accepting the answer,  which next part? adding a space before `NAME`  will not do a greedy search.

Comment: @Kris : Sorry that looks like a completely new requirement. You may delete the above comment and please consider posting a new question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your suggestion.